# ¿Por que no me funciona el método GetImageData de Canvas?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

Mi pregunta es ¿Por que no funciona la función getImageData en mi navegador?
Esta función debería de convertir la imagen a escala de grises y deja de funcionar cuando pongo la imagen en el canvas...

El método que sigo es este y me funciona a medias, llega a poner la imagen en el canvas pero esta no se convierte a grises en el bucle porque no funciona getImageData.

```
function ConvertirGrises() {
   var c = document.getElementById("MyCanvas");
   var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
   var img = document.getElementById("Imagen");
   ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0, c.width, c.height);
   var imgData = ctx.getImageData(0, 0, c.width, c.height);
   // convert gray colors
   var i;
   for (i = 0; i < imgData.data.length; i += 4) {
      var ElGris = (0.299 * imgData.data[i]) + (0.587 * imgData.data[i + 1]) + (0.114 * imgData.data[i + 2]);
      imgData.data[i] = ElGris;
      imgData.data[i + 1] = ElGris;
      imgData.data[i + 2] = ElGris;
      imgData.data[i + 3] = 255;
   }
   ctx.putImageData(imgData, 0, 0);
}
```

Comment: No estoy totalmente seguro, pero la asignación que haces, es de TODO el elemento, talvez te falte colocar algo especifico, tipo `.getElementById().data` porque estás asignando todos los parametros del elemento, y pues, me suena a que deba de ser algo especifico. Ademas, si imprimes en consola, que te sale??

Comment: El fallo esta al hacer la llamada a getImageData el cual no asigna el array a la variable imgData , lo hago cómo pone en la w3Schools y nada... 
Es muy raro me van todas las otras funciones de canvas pero es esta en concreto que no me va. Además va cuando no cargo ninguna imagen y cuando cargo la imagen deja de ir.